# How to create vector fields in Python and apply them to an image?

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a set of vectors with which I want to create a vector field with a specific resolution. My vectors are defined by their x,y positions and their lengths and angles.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import pylab as pl

theta_array = [3,5,7,1]
length_array = [4,6,7,8]
x_array = [4,7,8,9]
y_array = [7,3,5,8]

x = np.linspace(1,10,10)
y = np.linspace(1,10,10)

new_theta = griddata(x_array,y_array,theta_array,x,y,interp='linear')
new_length = griddata(x_array,y_array,length_array,x,y,interp='linear')
```

I want to create a `(10x10)` vector field from the interpolation of these vectors. Above I used `griddata` from matplotlib.

While it returns a 10x10 array with interpolated values, it only creates an island of data and `--` values for the other array elements.

```
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- 5.0 -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- 5.4 -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- 4.6 5.8 7.0 -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- 3.8 5.0 5.0 5.0 -- --]
 [-- -- -- 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1.0 --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True False False False  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True False False False False  True  True]
 [ True  True  True False False False False False  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

I would have wanted all elements to have values, fading/decreasing in value as it goes away from the elements which have values. Much like this:

[image: Rotational Vector Field]

A followup question to this would be how do I apply this to another image and morph it using the vector field?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve

Comment: @irenemeanspeace - Did you manage? If you figured out some elegant solution, don't be shy and answer your own question :) I'm interested in a solution for this same problem and any advancement you made would be useful.